# Sublime Text 3: Are disabled (ignored) packages loaded into memory?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime Text 3 on my OS X 10.9 suffers from significant typing lag.

Before I start start removing installed packages, I would like to ask if disabling a package (adding it to the `ignored_packages` list) prevents it from being loaded into memory.

IF that is the case then I can safely disable packages rather than remove them, which is is a greater hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Disabling Packages**
>
> To temporarily disable packages, you can add them to the ignored_packages list in your Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings file. Packages will be loaded or unloaded as needed when the settings file is saved.

*Source: [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#disabling-packages)*

To answer your question. Yes, you can try disabling packages to single out the one causing your performance issues; without uninstalling any of the packages.